# Why I must specify whole string in Java regular expression?

Tags: java, regex

Suppose, I have a string:

```
String str = "some strange string with searched symbol";
```

And I want to search in it some symbols, suppose it will be `"string"`. So we have a following:

```
str.matches("string"); //false
str.matches(".*string.*"); //true
```

So, as stated in the title, **why I must specify whole string in Java regular expression?**

Java documentation says:

> public boolean matches(String regex)
>
> Tells whether or not this string matches the given regular expression.

It doesn't says

> Tells whether or not this **whole** string matches the given regular expression.

For example, in the `php` it would be:

```
$str = "some strange string with searched symbol";
var_dump(preg_match('/string/', $str)); // int(1)
var_dump(preg_match('/.*string.*/', $str)); //int(1)
```

So, both of the regex's will be `true`.
And I think this is correct, because if I want to test whole string I would do `str.matches("^string$");`

**PS:** Yes, I know that is to search a **substring**, simpler and faster will be to use `str.indexOf("string")` or `str.contains("string")`. My question regards only to Java regular expression.

---

**UPDATE**: As stated by @ChrisJester-Young (and @GyroGearless) one of the solutions, if you want to search `regex` that is part of a subject string, is to use `find()` method like this:

```
    String str = "some strange string with searched symbol";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("string").matcher(str);
    System.out.println(m.find()); //true
```

Comment: you may use `find` func inside `if`.

Comment: Javadoc for class `Matcher` is pretty clear on that: "The matches method attempts to match the entire input sequence against the pattern."

Comment: Java has few problems with unintuitional methods naming in regex department. For instance `replace(str, str)` vs `replaceAll(str, str)`. It is not obvious that *only* difference between these two is that `replace` doesn't use regex syntax while `replaceAll` does (both methods will replace all occurrences or selected text). Unfortunately all we can do now is just accept this, made our share of errors and finally get used to it.

Comment: Because regular expression "string" doesn't match your test string. The function behaves exactly like documentation says. I suggest reading a bit more about regexes, this should help with future misunderstandings.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`matches` always matches the whole input string. If you want to allow substrings to match, use `find`.

Comment: You mean: `Pattern.compile("string").matcher(str).find()` ?

Comment: @spirit Correct. Sadly there is no fancy convenience function on the `String` class for it. :-(

Comment: Agreed =) It would be better if there was a `str.find("regex")` method.

Comment: Well, there is `indexOf(String)` ... .

Comment: @KevinEsche Well yes, but `find` is a much closer analogue to `matches` in terms of functionality.

Comment: @Fildor ....except there isn't. String.indexOf() does not take a regex as parameter. Only a fixed String.

Answer (score 3):

As the documentation you suggest,

> public boolean matches(String regex)
>
> Tells whether or not this string matches the given regular expression.

What it means is whether that string **matches** with the given regex. i.e. `matches` verifies whether your string is an **instance** of the given regex.

**not** whether it contains a substring which is an **instance** of the given regex. As Chris suggested you can use `find` instead or for your problem you can use `contains`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as you already know (now) that `matches()` will return true only for the complete string.

But, in your update, you have stated that:

> As stated by @ChrisJester-Young (and @GyroGearless) the *only* solution, if you want to search regex that is part of a subject string, is to use find() method...

I would like to say that using `find()` is **not the only solution**. There is at least one more, which I know :

```
String str = "some strange string with searched symbol";
boolean found = str.split("string").length>1;
System.out.println(found);
```

This prints `true`. And this will work for all regular expressions. Though this is not the way to do it, and is instead a hack.

There may be many more solutions.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there are a lot of **hacks** to achive same result =). I was telling about the *right* way to achive this. But now I understand, that's that was only my opinion. Removed *only* =)

Comment: @spirit You removed only the only only in your only question? Only? Ok. Only! :P