# Regular expression in java not working

Tags: java, regex, formatter

I convert a excel file to a CSV , and that to a String.

The problem is that a regular expression is not working correctly

I want to detect this kind of text:

> MYW Pkg, MYW Pkg + Quick Service Dining, MYW Pkg + Dining, MYW Pkg +
>   Deluxe Dining,
>
> Room + Tickets + Quick Service Dining

I have an array of String.
So I need to know a pattern for that, I try this but it doesn't detect it:

```
Pattern.compile("([A-Z]{3})+(\\s)+([A-Za-z]{3})+(\\s)+(\\+)");
```

I try to match "MYW Pkg +" for example,
Do you know why it is not working?

More code:

chain is the array with values like "MYW Pkg,"

```
Pattern patPackageDescription = Pattern.compile("([A-Z]{3})+(\\s)+([A-Za-z])+(\\s)+(\\+)");
        for (int i = 0; i < chain.length; i++) {
            Matcher matPackageDescription = patPackageDescription
                    .matcher(chain[i]);

            if (matPackageDescription.matches()) {
                String space = String.format("%1$-" + 50 + "s",
                        chain[i].toString());
                a.append(space + "|\n");
            }
        }
```

Regards.

Comment: What parts of the above string are you trying to match. Two things I will point out are 1) `(?)` is weird / most likely not necessary and 2) you're looking for `[A-Z]+` right before `\\+` (even though there's a space between `Pkg` and `+`).

Comment: @Sam I try to match "MYW Pkg +" at least, and anubhava (?) is not for case sensitive?

Comment: Inline case insensitive modifier will look like `(?i:[A-Z])`, but you can just use `[A-Za-z]`

Comment: Still not reaching any result :( I added the regExp to the question

Comment: show us a little bit more of your code

Comment: code has been added

Comment: I would recommend using https://www.debuggex.com/ to debug regex problems

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`matches()` method tries to match the whole string against the pattern, to match a part of the string you need to use `find()` method.

```
String str = "MYW Pkg, MYW Pkg + Quick Service Dining, MYW Pkg + Dining, MYW Pkg + Deluxe Dining,";
Pattern patPackageDescription = Pattern.compile("([A-Za-z]{3}\\s)+\\+");
Matcher matPackageDescription = patPackageDescription.matcher(str);

while (matPackageDescription.find()) {
    System.out.println(matPackageDescription.group());
}
```

Outputs:

```
MYW Pkg +
MYW Pkg +
MYW Pkg +
```

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38183275/why-i-must-specify-whole-string-in-java-regular-expression) for an explanation.

Comment: Is correct what you say I add (.*) for a correct match  .. so ([A-Za-z]{n}\\s)+(\\+)+([A-Za-z]{n}\\s)+(\\+)+(.*) That should serve for these cases: MYW Pkg + Quick Service Dining , Room + Tickets + Quick Service Dining..... Right?

Comment: How can I place n for any number?

Comment: @arnoldssss, tell me what exactly do you need to do =) So I can help you than.

Comment: I need to detect in my array of String things like:
Room + Tickets + Quick Service Dining,
MYW Pkg + Quick Service Dining.
So I need to know ... why this regex is not working

"([A-Za-z]{1,}\\s)+(\\+)+([A-Za-z]{1,}\\s)+(\\+)+(.*)"

Comment: oh I see my issue now.. htere are differences in both Strings... I´ll give your answer as good.. thanks

Comment: you are welcome. But I think, you use overcomplicated regex's =). For example, you don't need parenthesises that much.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using `Matcher.matches()` which requires a full match, if you can either use `find()` for partial matches or add `.*` to match anything after your search string.

```
([A-Z]{3})+(\s)+([A-Za-z]{3})+(\s)+(\+).*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/JUWfNuL6NL7-5oB9)

Comment: cool I add it .. so ([A-Za-z]{n}\\s)+(\\+)+([A-Za-z]{n}\\s)+(\\+)+(.*)
That should serve for these cases: MYW Pkg + Quick Service Dining

And

Room + Tickets + Quick Service Dining

Right?

Comment: if your string will start from something like number, it will fail. you need to add `.*?` to the beginning of your regex too